# Как преобразовать Enum в FString?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

Как в C++ преобразовать Enum в FString?

Аналогично функции C# Enum.parse?

```
enum class types{
  ONE,
  TWO
}
```

Comment: Создать, например, массив или `map` имен...

Comment: То есть автоматически никак в С++ unreal?

Comment: Ну скормите его перегруженной функции, а в неё запихайте преобразование, в каждой версии своё для своего типа енама. Это ж не питон со своими проблемами, а плюсы, конкретно от этих проблем избавленные. И можно всё сделать, как принято на плюсах.

Comment: Скажите, а зачем вам это надо? Может, вы выясняете, в какой руке держать микроскоп, вместо чтоб выяснить, как удобнее забивать гвозди?... :)

Comment: Ну везде есть возможность вывода Enum в строку. Иначе какой смысл в enum? Тогда проще использовать обычные числа.

Comment: @manking, смысл в enum?  Это именование бит как  выражение, известное во время компиляции _  какраз и придается смысл обычным цифрам с помощью enum, а обычные цифры в коде ни о чем не говорят для чего они и какая у них роль

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию из самого Unreal GetValueAsString.

```
EUnitClass type;
UEnum::GetValueAsString(type);
```